# google app engine outgoing traffic costs

Tags: google-app-engine, traffic

I am little confused about outoging traffic cost in GAE projects.
see: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/pricingandterms

So, if u use GAE outgoing traffic costs $0.12 always. However if google cloud storage service is used, u get higher cost ($0.21) when sending data to Asia. Why is that?

So this basically mean, if i send 100GB of data to Asia via my GAE app, it will cost me $12, but if i publish my data in public cloud storage buckets, same 100GB transfered would cost $21. Or am i wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.

To save monthly costs (not development costs), you can serve your content from your GAE instance.  You can essentially have a relay functionality in your GAE to serve content from your cloud storage. Is it worth the $0.10/GB, only you'll know based on your traffic demands.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that Google Storage will use ETag headers which might actually reduce the amount of traffic your app is serving if it is mainly static content. So even though you might pay more per GB to certain geographic locations you might actually serve less data.